# In string theory 2D holographic universe, what is matter?

Tags: string-theory

In string theory,the universe is only 2Dimensional on the cosmic horizon. My question is, if that is the case, then what is matter according to this? Are the strings and branes physically there on the 2D horizon, or is everything simply bits of information on the horizon, and we are just a projection of that information?

Comment: Where have you read that? What is cosmic horizon in your definition?

Comment: It seems like you have been misinformed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First let's consider the math of this. Our world is described, at least approximately, by a quantum field theory in 3-dimensonal space, that consists of the standard model, plus general relativity, plus some extra fields to account for neutrino masses and "dark matter" effects. A holographic dual theory, that lived at the cosmological horizon, would be a quantum field theory in a closed 2-dimensional space (equivalent to the horizon). It would have a different set of fields - I will call them "holographic preons" since preon is a standard name for a subquark particle - but this 2D QFT of holographic preons would somehow be equivalent to the 3D QFT of SM + GR + extras.

How would this work? To a large degree, it's like shadows on the wall of a dark room, illuminated by a single source of light - let's say a candle. An object close to the wall casts a small shadow, but an object close to the candle casts an enormous shadow. Reverse this, and you see how the emergent dimension works in holography. Basically, in order to reach into the extra dimension - here, the 3rd dimension - you average over a region of the holographic fields (the 2d preons). The larger the 2d region, the deeper its holographic counterpart lies in the 3rd dimension - just like the shadows, but in reverse.

Here is a [talk](http://www.phys.vt.edu/sowers/talks/kabat.pdf) about how this works for AdS/CFT. See the pictures on slides 10 and 11: a whole region in 2d, corresponds to a point deep into the 3rd dimension... Since these are quantum field theories, we are really talking about probabilities. The probabilistic behavior, of one of our 3d fields, at a certain point in space, should be *identical* to the probabilistic behavior, of the right combination of preon fields on the 2d horizon, averaged across the appropriate region. And that is how it works in AdS/CFT: the "preons" are, for example, the fields of N=4 super-Yang-Mills theory, and they combine to describe vibrational modes of strings and branes in an anti de Sitter space of one extra dimension.

But that's for AdS, a negatively curved space that is the opposite of the real world. There is almost no work developing holographic duality for cosmological horizons in de Sitter space. There are some sketchy papers (e.g. by Edi Halyo or Miao Li) which never caught on. There's [one by Eva Silverstein's group](http://arxiv.org/abs/1005.5403) which might be a working example, since they claim to explain the entropy of the horizon; I'll have to read it again.

In fact, the majority of attempts to apply holography to de Sitter space (under the name dS/CFT), try to obtain the (3+1)-dimensional universe, not from a (2+1)-dimensional horizon theory, but rather from a timeless (3+0)-dimensional theory at the end of time. In this case, it's time that emerges holographically as the extra dimension; with times in the distant past, corresponding to averages over large spatial regions of the timeless theory. And so far dS/CFT is very problematic - there are very few examples, and the "timeless theories" have peculiar properties, like fermionic scalars.

So realizing holography in the real world, whether as you suggest (dual to the cosmological horizon) or in this other way (dual to the end of time!), is proving quite difficult. There is at least one more version of holography, a sort of holography for flat space, in which the "description with one less dimension" is basically the world as seen when moving at the speed of light ("infinite momentum frame"). Everything in the direction of motion is made infinitely thin by relativistic length contraction, and so you effectively have one less dimension. This is also realized in string theory, by what's called "Matrix theory", and maybe it's halfway between AdS duality and dS-horizon duality.

Anyway, holographic duality is a work in progress, those are the messy details as I understand them. Now to turn to your question: in a holographic world, what is reality? What's actually there? Here I think the best guide is a return to the basics of quantum mechanics. In quantum mechanics, the things that *can* exist are the "observables" - properties like the energy and angular momentum of an object, the position and state of motion of an object, or the strength and rate of change of a field. A quantum theory gives probabilistic predictions for what such properties might be, within the limits of the uncertainty principle.

Because of the uncertainty principle (or whatever equivalent axiom you use to define quantum theory), a quantum theory can't give you a description of the world as complete as a classical theory, but it can come close. You can think in terms of a maximum set of "commuting observables" - commuting means that they can exist simultaneously without violating the uncertainty principle. That would be like a universe of classical physics, but a little coarse-grained - not with the same resolution of reality.

OK, that was a deviation into the ontology of quantum theory, now back to the question of ontology of *holographic* quantum theory. The thing about holographic duality, is that it offers two descriptions of the same thing. In our hypothetical realistic example of the real world, "SM + GR + extras", one description uses observables from that slight extension of the standard model. The ontology of the coarse-grained quantum universe would consist of things like electromagnetic field densities, and electron and quark number densities.

The other description is in terms of the preon fields on the horizon. There's some mapping between, like, "photon number at coordinates (x,t)" and "average density of preon bound state X, over horizon region corresponding to (x,t)". In other words, for every 3d observable, there is a corresponding averaged 2d observable. So just judging by empirical adequacy, there would be no way to decide whether the standard model fields, or the holographic preon fields, are more real. Even from the preon perspective, reality still ends up being (3+1)-dimensional in a sense, because you have to say that reality consists, not just of "things on the horizon", but "averages of regions on the horizon" that are holographically equivalent to "things inside the horizon".

From a practical perspective, it might be wisest to regard the 3d picture as more real, and the 2d picture as just a clever alternative description, at least until everything is much better understood. The radicals in theoretical physics are always saying that space and time as a whole will turn out to be "emergent" or not fundamental; though it's hard to see how you could *entirely abolish* concepts like "here" vs "there", or "now" vs "later", and still be talking about reality! But we certainly might end up with a world-picture in which the connections between here and there, or now and later, are less like checkers, and more like snakes-and-ladders. And holography might consist of sliding down the snake, or climbing up the ladder. :-)